# PassportJs: Cannot GET /auth/facebook/callback

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I am trying to use passportjs to login using facebook services. There are a lot of examples online, but none that really explicitly illustrate an implementation with no persistent sessions as I plan to use JWTs to identify my users.

I have tried to this on my own but I keep getting an error response `Cannot GET /auth/facebook/callback`. See my implementation below.

Routes file

```
router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ scope : ['email'] }));
router.get('/facebook/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        session: false
    }));
```

Passportjs

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebookAppId,
    clientSecret: config.facebookAppSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebookCallbackURL,
    profileFields: ['email']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //find the user based off of the facebook profile id
    User.findOne({oauthID: profile.id}).exec()

    //find the user or create a new record
    .then(function(user){
      if(user) return done(null, user);

      var user = new User({
        oauthID: profile.id,
        oauthProvider: 'facebook',
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        name: profile.displayName
      });
      user.save();
    })

    //send back error if encountered
    .catch(done);
  }
));
```

Comment: You can not use AJAX to call the login dialog.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for responding. This is a an express backend.maybe I should have made that clear.

Comment: I don’t see how that changes anything.

Comment: @CBroe mind expanding on your answer? Not sure what you are referring to?

Comment: `router.get` loads stuff via AJAX, no?

Comment: lol not necessarily. router.get() is just an entry point to an application. The handler is the passport.authenticate() function. I am not super familiar with the handler from this library and need help understanding why my implementation fails. A lot of articles online give an example with persistent sessions but I do not want sessions to be involved.

Comment: So where from does that error message originate? A normal request in the browser would not show such an error, so it comes from somewhere in the code. And if the code itself is making GET requests that fail … it’s likely AJAX …?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your api path. In my case I use api path like http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/auth/facebook/callback which is use in postman and its working but when I try from my reactJs Form there I used http://127.0.0.1:3001/auth/facebook/callback so I am getting this error Cannot GET /auth/facebook/callback. When I fix this path from this http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/auth/facebook/callback my form is working and I saw facebook login page.

I hope it will work for you. Thankyou